# making rails form_for compatible with bootstrap form w/o using a gem.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a bootstrap form out of a rails form_for and have the input save to my rails database. In the code below I make a div class of "form-group" and have a label and input. The label for accepts my rails code and has the label "Your Reminder". However, when i try and pass my rails variable :text into the input tag it does not store the variable input in my rails database. The code below the div tags works and will successfully pass the input to my database but not when i run it in the div tags.

What I'm curious about is where in the  do i put my <%= f.text_area :text %> and how should it be styled?

```
   <%= form_for @reminder do |f|%>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="exampleReminder"><%=f.label "Your Reminder" %></label>
         <input type="[<%:text%>]" class="form-control" id="exampleReminder" placeholder="Enter Your Reminder">
        </div>


<%= f.label "your reminder" %>
<%= f.text_area :text %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `form-control` class to the text fields using the `text_field` helper.

```
<%= form_for @reminder do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :text, "Your Reminder" %>
    <%= f.text_field :text, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter Your Reminder" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```